# Cocos2d crash when using dictation (microphone button) with CCTextField

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, dictation

I get a permanent crash when tapping on microphone button during the input in CCTextField. There's no crash on iPhone 4s iOS8, but the game is crashed on iPhone 5s iOS9 and iPhone 6+ iOS9. This issue seems to be the same as described here http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/engine-crash-on-ios7/9129/10 and there's a solution for cocos2d-x there. Can someone provide a solution for cocos2d-objc ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, here's the workaround for cocos2d-objc:

```
- (void) update:(CCTime)delta{
    CCGLView *ccglView = (CCGLView *)[[CCDirector sharedDirector] view];
    [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:ccglView.context];
}
```